# Can't read arabic txt file in PHP

Tags: php, file, arabic

I have so many text(.txt) files and I want to read it with PHP and display in web browser. Some of my files is in arabic language.

I am using file_get_contents function to read files. But I can't get proper result.

Here is sample of what I is my input and output.

```
Input Text ===> لة إلى الشعب الأردني العزيز والى شعوب العالم الحر والى المنظمات الدولية  للحرية وحقوق الإنسان والى معاقل الديم


Output Text ===> J2 H'DI 49H( 'D9'DE 'D-1 H'DI 'DEF8E'* 'D/HDJ) DD-1J) H-BHB 'D%F3'F H'DI E9'BD 'D/JEHB
```

My page is has already UTF-8 charset. I have also tried fopen function and still same result.
What I am missing?

Comment: How exactly are your files encoded/saved as?

Comment: Actually we have another software which is generating files. I don't know files are generated in which charset and I know this is the main problem.

Comment: I am trying to detect charset with mb_detect_encoding but it returns false.

Comment: Figure out what encoding that stuff is in. You won't get anywhere unless you do.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" /> -->
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $file = "arabic.txt";
        $data = file_get_contents($file);
        echo $data; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

, where arabic.txt is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Still works: http://i.imgur.com/VqM1bxo.png (wrapped in <pre> tags for formatting)

Comment: Oh,
it means issue is with my charset of file. My file is generated by other system. So I don't know about charset of file. I have tried mb_detect_encoding but it returns false.

It is working for you because I think you have save files as utf 8.

By the way thank for help.

Comment: Could try this: Open the file, save as utf8 and use that.

Comment: It works for me if I create new file and use same content but this is not the case here. I can't generate file myself. We have another system is generating all files dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html'; charset='UTF-8'/>
<body>
<?php 
//put your file in this folder
$path='D:\test';
$files=scandir($path);

foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
    if($value!="." && $value!="..")
    {
        print_r(file_get_contents($path."/".$value));

    }
}
?>
</body>
<html>
```

you can see : [How to print all the txt files inside a folder with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628990/how-to-print-all-the-txt-files-inside-a-folder-with-php)