# How to print all the txt files inside a folder with php?

Tags: php

How to write all the txt files contents in a folder to an html page, besides i don't know the files names, i tried this but it didn't work:

```
<?php
$files=scandir("D:\\new\places");
foreach (files as value)
echo (files);
?>
```

Comment: try it <?php foreach($files as $value) { echo $value;}  ?>

Comment: Use `$` in php variable Try `foreach ($files as $value) echo ($value);`

Comment: please paste your full code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use following php code to get content of the files.

```
$path='../innovation';
$files=scandir($path);
//print_r($files);
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
    if($value!="." && $value!="..")
    {
        print_r(file_get_contents($path."/".$value));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you your code worked for me, but i need to change the unicode of the txt file is that possible on php or i need to do this from the origin files?

Answer (score 1):

[`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) is ideal for this, since it streams the files directly to the output buffer, which will avoid memory issues for large files.

```
<?php
$path = 'myDirectory';

$files = glob("{$path}/*.txt");

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    readfile($file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$directory = "./foldername";    
$files = glob($directory . "*.txt");    
foreach($files as $file){
    $file = fopen($directory . '/' . $file,'r');    
    while ($line = fgets($file)) {    
        echo($line);    
    }    
    fclose($fh);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all the text files (.txt) from a directory to HTML using PHP you can use this code to do it:

```
<?php 
echo '<ul>';

// set the path to the directory...   
$dirname = "directory/";

$files = glob($dirname."*.txt");
foreach($files as $file) {
echo '<li>'.$file.'</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob()` to get all *.txt files in a directory. After loop through every file with a `foreach` loop and get the content of each file using `file_get_contents`() and put the content into the target file with `file_put_contents()`

```
<?php

    $files = glob("path/*.txt");
    $output = "output.txt";

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $content = file_get_contents($file);
        print_r($content);
    }

?>
```